# c# how to directly choose the excel message box in winform

Tags: c#, excel

I am developing a winform program to operate excel. However, Excel prompt a messagebox such as 'want to save your changes to ...'.

And I hope if I can run this program automatically without click the message. Are there any code to directly choose the option?

Comment: What is your program actually doing? Does it really need Excel interop?

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: what do you mean by "operate excel" specifically? If you're just trying to read and write Excel files, then you can use a different library which works directly on the files without needing the Excel application.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = null;
excelApp = new Excel.Application();

//suppress displaying alerts
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
```